# Firebase query multiple keys Android client

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 14 attributes in facedetails I want to query on and find the closest match for each, and only if the 14 attributes match person face My code will return the person object.
Here is a sample on the database:

```
"faceDetails":{
    "mCalculateFaceSizeHeight" : 121,
    "mCalculateFaceSizeWidth" : 107,
    "mCalculateLeftEyeBrowSizeHeight" : 31,
    "mCalculateLeftEyeBrowSizeWidth" : 43,
    "mCalculateLeftEyeSizeHeight" : 64,
    "mCalculateLeftEyeSizeWidth" : 10,
    "mCalculateMouthSizeHeight" : 24,
    "mCalculateMouthSizeWidth" : 30,
    "mCalculateNoseSizeHeight" : 43,
    "mCalculateNoseSizeWidth" : 71,
    "mCalculateRightEyeBrowSizeHeight" : 43,
    "mCalculateRightEyeBrowSizeWidth" : 52,
    "mCalculateRightEyeSizeWidth" : 14,
    "mCalculatedRightEyeSizeHeight" : 36
            }
```

Currently in the Android device I have something like this.

```
Query personLeftEyeSizeWidthQueryendAt = myRef.orderByChild("mCalculateLeftEyeSizeWidth")
                .endAt(mCalculateLeftEyeSizeWidth())
                .limitToLast(1);
        personLeftEyeSizeWidthQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {....

Query personLeftEyeSizeWidthQueryStartAt = myRef.orderByChild("mCalculateLeftEyeSizeWidth")
                    .startAt(mCalculateLeftEyeSizeWidth())
                    .limitToFirst(1);
            personLeftEyeSizeWidthQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {....


My index is like this:
".indexOn": [
        "mCalculateLeftEyeSizeWidth",
        "mCalculateLeftEyeSizeHeight",
        "mCalculateRightEyeSizeWidth",
        "mCalculatedRightEyeSizeHeight",
        "mCalculateNoseSizeWidth",
        "mCalculateNoseSizeHeight",
        "mCalculateMouthSizeWidth",
        "mCalculateMouthSizeHeight",
        "mCalculateLeftEyeBrowSizeWidth",
        "mCalculateLeftEyeBrowSizeHeight",
        "mCalculateRightEyeBrowSizeWidth",
        "mCalculateRightEyeBrowSizeHeight",
        "mCalculateFaceSizeWidth",
        "mCalculateFaceSizeHeight"

      ]
```

My question is do I move forward with 28 single queries each one single query  or there is better way to combine all 28.
I do not want to give up on some of them as face recognition accuracy is very important for finding a match.
Let me know if should I continue with 28 single query then check the key of each one to see that they are all matching the same person or maybe another method.

Thanks
Eran Gross

Comment: Check my answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156902/make-firebaserecycleradapter-get-data-under-conditions-and-not-all-of-them/46384299#46384299

Answer (score 2):

Current Firebase Database API does not provide exact way for combining queries.
However, in [the video](https://youtu.be/sKFLI5FOOHs?t=565) person from Firebase tells how to structure your database to relieve the burden.
 I suggest, instead of seperating `leftEyeHeight` and `leftEyeWidth` you can merge them up by simply `leftEyeSize` whose value could be written as `(leftEyeHeight, leftEyeWidth)` This will halve your problem even if you write each query manualy

Comment: Not sure it will work merge two values.
The DB understand number int string that is why I divided it to begin with so
 .startAt(mCalculateLeftEyeSizeWidth()) return int and search that value.
if you combine the values to point(widht,height)  so for example
mCalculateLeftEyeSize() = (14,20)
then the DB will not be able to search on.
.startAt(mCalculateLeftEyeSize()) = > this will not work.
I did not try that on Firebase but already tested few DB, they do not understand point values ...

Comment: Did you look at this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase?rq=1

Comment: I am looking at the source code.
Query.class = > .startAt and .endAt
boolean
String
Double

Comment: Yes I saw that already, in the example they are combining multiple string.
then search on root string...
The Firebase recommended flat Database as possible .
Eventually I need the number value to run the query . 
I do not want to combine the actual value like 
like eyeSize = width * height return eyeSize

Comment: I hope they will release an update which they provide a better Query class